# Why Drupal won't remember "use search" permission settings for roles?

Tags: users, search

I want to make search available to everyone who uses the site, including anonymous users.
Now, if i go to */admin/people/permissions* and and try to enable "use search" for anonymous and authenticated users, the systems seems to act okay, but when I look at it again, nothing's changed. The settings seemingly won't remember my settings. 
Any ideas? I hope that there's something totally simple I forgot

EDIT: in fact, it does not keep any changes in the permission system.

EDIT 2: I made it work by editing permissions through /admin/people/permissions/roles. Does anyone has any ideas why it was possible in one way but not the other?

Comment: Sounds like a bug; did you try on a clean install?

Comment: no, I've done a fair number of them, and that's the first time I have this problem. That's exactly what makes me wonder.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a default setting of 1000 for max_input_vars, and once you have a significant number of modules and/or roles defined, you end up with an excess number of permissions boxes on the page.

In your php.ini file add max_input_vars = 1500 and keep incrementally increasing it until it saves.

Comment: ...and, re: edit 2, with only one role shown, you are under this limit.